# text become blur in textarea after firstline in crome only

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, textarea, blur

```
<Form.Control
                            
                            as='textarea'
                            autoFocus={true}
                            className='textarea-style'
                            
                            ref={register}
                            name='notes'
                            isInvalid={!!errors.notes}
                            disabled={false}
                            placeholder={
                              embroideryDetails?.formData
                                ?.notesTextboxPlaceholder ||
                              'Tell us any other requirements...'
                            }
                          />
```

```
.textarea-style{
  resize: none;
  overflow: auto;
  backdrop-filter: none;
  text-rendering: auto;
}
```

Can any one tell me why the text become blur in textarea when the text goes to second line and this is only happen in crome browser

Can any one tell me why the text become blur in textarea when the text goes to second line and this is only happen in crome browser